# Search Results Formatting

Tags: php, css

I was struck with a Problem of displaying the search results. Here is my piece of code

```
<style>
    .main {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 1.01vw;
        color: Black;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        top: 13.5vw;
        left: 28.4%;
    }
</style>

<style>
    .details {
        position: absolute;
        font: 1.19vw;
        color: Black;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        top: 28%;
        left: 28.4%;
    }
</style>

<?php

$input = $_GET['input'] or die (mysql_error());
$terms = explode(" ", $input);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

$first = true;

foreach ($terms as $each) {
    if ($first) {
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $query .= "OR keyword LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
}

//Connect to Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("databasem") or die ("database not found");

$query = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        echo "<div class=\"main\"><h2><a href='$link' style='text-decoration:none'><b>$title</b></a></h2>$description<br/></div>";
    }
    echo "<br /><br />$numrows Results Found\n";
} else {
    echo "<div class=\"details\">No Results Found <b>'$input'</b> </div>";
}
```

The search results are displaying on top of each other instead of one after the other.

I am a novice to PHP and this is my 1st ever program in my life. I know that the coding style is too old and will try to improve my coding styles in the near future. Kindly correct me if there is some sort of update in the code.

Thanks

Comment: If the results are not displayed correctly it is most likely a CSS issue.

Comment: Ok thanks..... I changed it to Position:relative;

Comment: How to reduce the spacing between $title and $description... I haven't used any <br> between them but still there's a line gapping over there

Comment: Press F12 or right click the element and Select "Inspect element" you'll be able to see the CSS applied and such, it's properly a padding or margin, google some CSS tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the CSS rather than the PHP -

```
.main {
  position: absolute;
  ...
  top:13.5vw;
  left:28.4%;
```

[Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition) means text is always displayed in exactly the same place on the screen - and because for each result you're creating another`<div>` of class `.main` it'll just get written over the top.

Generally, only using position: absolute when "absolutely" necessary – it's useful for things like navigation bars or logos that have to be in a specific position on screen, but it's problematic with variable amounts of text.  If you have a list, use `inline`,`block` or `inline-block` to allow the browser to flow the text itself.

I'd suggest:

As it's your first program and guessing you may have just copied the CSS from somewhere else, delete everything except the font settings, and for your results, use something like this to print each result:

```
echo("<li> <h2>$title</h2> $description </li>");
```

(wrap this in an [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) - `<ul>` and `</ul>` - around your `while` statement.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the <ul> properties. I need to display the results in a specific part of the page which intended me to use those left and right set of properties with a Position property of relative..